# User insert commas into text field deletes data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems inserting commas (,) in my text fields in html. When I submit it to mysql, it deletes the data. How do I work with this?

I've tried mysql_real_escape_string() but that still doesn't work. I have lots of data, and I don't want to use str_replace either. Is there another alternative?

Comment: I can't even imagine the level of wrong it would take to make commas break SQL, let alone delete something. Could you describe the problem a bit better? Preferably with sample code.

Comment: @amadan, I agree the deletion is confusing, but the breaking makes sense, if he's inserting and the raw field comes back with commas which makes the query think he's moving on to the next data field. Though clearly this implies all sorts of incorrect usage... but hey... that's not the question, right? :)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel, I kind of thought about it, and the only thing I could see is using unprocessed string input as numeric values in SQL (i.e. no quotes). It should not delete data. Your suggestion of escaping does not help then, BTW. :)

Comment: thanks for the help guys :) I was able to solve the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

escape your message before you send it to the server, so it's stored escaped, then unescape it when you print it in your html page.

so... msgTosend = escape(whateverText);

and then when you're printing
msgToPrint = getFromDatabase(unescape(myText))

however, as the comment points out, you're obviously doing something dreadfully wrong altogether.

If you're storing strings (as it sounds) you need to be wrapping them in quotes before you store them. Once you do that no amount of commas can ruin anything.  If you're not storing strings, but some other data type, then you should be breaking those out into individual variables on the server before storing anything. The potential for malice or just plain breakage is basically 100% with what it sounds like you're doing.

Comment: Oh you're right. Its because I didn't put quotes around my values. I think because it was an integer I thought that it didn't need quotes, but if someone needed to put numbers and have commas included, then it would mess up my dad. The quotes fixed my string. thanks guys!